# simplehtmldom 500 error

Tags: simple-html-dom

I saw that there are a lot of topics on simplehtmldom, but no one's problem seems to be mine- specifically, that it just 500s, even on the examples provided.  I've found that I can include the file without an error, but if I then try to use file_get_html, it 500s.  The only thing I found in the manual about installation is a possible problem with allow_fopen_url, which I do.

Something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like too long since you asked this question, but since I came across this trying to solve this problem myself, I thought I'd post what worked for me.

I solved this problem by changing `file_get_html` to `file_get_contents`. Since I wanted to use the 'find' feature in `simple_html_dom`, I had to then convert the string to an object:

```
$string = file_get_contents(http://thedeadfallproject.com/)
$object = new simple_html_dom();
$object->load($string); // Load HTML from a string
```

Comment: Heh, I ended up finding the same fix.  Cheers!