# dompdf and codeigniter - error 500 when execute load_html

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf, internal-server-error

I have an error 500 with this code:

```
require_once FCPATH.'application/helpers/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html( $html );
$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents( './tmp/'.$filename.'.pdf' , $pdf );
```

With some debug, I find that the "evil" code is this

```
$dompdf->load_html( $html );
```

And I don't know how to solve this.

Even the "ini_set" instruction with memory_limit and max_execution_time doesn't fix this problem..

Comment: Where is $html defined? It's not in the code you posted. What does it contain?

Comment: @DamienPirsy $html contains the $this->load->view( 'xyz.php', '', TRUE );

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380774/simplehtmldom-500-error/11917063

Comment: maybe you have white space before your header...

Answer (score 0):

1. Follow the advice [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2687747/568884). PHP is probably bubbling the error up to Apache.
2. Check the permissions on the file and parent folders of `application/helpers/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php`, ensure they are readable.
3. I believe that if you see a 500 error in the access log, there will also be a report in the error log. If not, the error is coming from PHP. Check your server logs. See `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and `var/log/apache2/access.log` on Linux.